# Menu Block - How to make a new menu automatically available?

Tags: blocks

How to automatically set a newly created menu as available so that it can immediately be used when configured for "the menu selected by the page"?

I've tried setting the 'menu_block_menu_order' variable through code, upon a new menu creation, but haven't figured it out.

What's the best way to automatically set a new menu , or all menus, as available?

Comment: did you clear the cache after creating the menu?

Comment: Are you trying to add a new menu item in a custom module?

Comment: yes via a custom module or rules php. i don't think the menu block module offers ability to modify the menu_block_menu_order via it's hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Menu Block module, but this seems to be the proper way of setting the menu_block_menu_order variable when a new menu is created:

```
function mymodule_menu_insert($menu) {
  $menus = variable_get('menu_block_menu_order', array('main-menu' => '', 'user-menu' => ''));
  $menus[$menu['menu_name']] = '';
  variable_set('menu_block_menu_order', $menus);
}
```

Comment: u dun it again!